# Android Parsing 

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

This is my XML:

```
<STATE sname="AndhraPradesh" >
    <DISTRICT dname="Ananthapur" >
        <address>
            Apollo Pharmacy, ANANTHAPUR (0.0 km)
            D.NO.15/545, NEAR SAPTHAGIRI CIRCLE ANANTHAPUR, Rayalaseema, ANANTHAPUR, ANATHAPUR , ANDHRA PRADESH
        </address>
    </DISTRICT>

    <DISTRICT dname="Kurnool" >
        <address>
            Apollo Pharmacy, KURNOOL (0.0 km)
            municipal no. D No: 46/697-A, Budwarpeta, KURNOOL, KURNOOL, ANDHRA PRADESH
        </address>
        <address>
            Apollo Pharmacy, KURNOOL 2 (0.0 km)
            1-155, Rayalaseema, KURNOOL 2, KURNOOL, ANDHRA PRADESH
        </address>
    </DISTRICT>

    <DISTRICT dname="EastGodawari" >

        <address>
            Apollo Pharmacy, VENKATESWAR COLONY (MAHABUB NAGAR) (0.0 km)
            D.No.7-4-58/A, Main Road Opp:A.P.S.E.B.Buliding, Mahabub, VENKATESWAR COLONY (MAHABUB NAGAR), HYDERABAD, ANDRA PRADESH
        </address>
        <address>
            Apollo Pharmacy, MAHABOOBNAGAR (0.0 km)
            1-5-35/6, Beside Andhrabank ATM, Mahaboobnagar, Telangana, MAHABOOBNAGAR, HYDERABAD, ANDHRA PRADESH
        </address>
        <address>
            Apollo Pharmacy, METTUGUDA - MAHABOOBANAGAR - 2 (0.0 km)
            1-4-30/D/B, Mahaboobnagar, METTUGUDA - MAHABOOBANAGAR - 2, HYDERABAD, ANDHRA PRADESH
        </address>
    </DISTRICT>

</STATE>

 <STATE sname="AndhraPradesh1111" >
    <DISTRICT dname="Ananthapur1111" >
        <address>
            Apollo Pharmacy, ANANTHAPUR (0.0 km)
        </address>
    </DISTRICT>

    <DISTRICT dname="Kurnool1111" >
        <address>
            Apollo Pharmacy, KURNOOL (0.0 km)
        </address>
        <address>
            Apollo Pharmacy, KURNOOL 2 (0.0 km)
        </address>
    </DISTRICT>

    <DISTRICT dname="EastGodawari1111" >

        <address>
            Apollo Pharmacy, VENKATESWAR COLONY (MAHABUB NAGAR) (0.0 km)
        </address>
        <address>
            Apollo Pharmacy, MAHABOOBNAGAR (0.0 km)
        </address>
        <address>
            Apollo Pharmacy, METTUGUDA - MAHABOOBANAGAR - 2 (0.0 km)
        </address>
    </DISTRICT>

</STATE>
```

I want to display the values in spinners. When I select state the related district must load in the district spinner. Based on the district spinner the addresses of that district should be loaded in the Text View.

Comment: Welcome to the Stackoverflow community. While asking questions here, if possible then show your work whatever you tried so far.

Comment: I'd have a look at [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

use the dom parsing 
//Read myxml.xml file from /res/raw folder
    InputStream is=getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.country);

```
Log.i("TAG","is value==>"+is);
DocumentBuilder builder=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc=builder.parse(is, null);

//get the root node
NodeList nodeList=doc.getElementsByTagName("STATE sname");

Log.i("TAG","nodeList Length --" + nodeList.getLength()); //output:- -1
Log.i("TAG","nodeList name --" + nodeList.item(0).getNodeName());
//output:- message
for(int j=0; j<nodeList.getLength(); j++) {
Node nodee=nodeList.item(j);
for(int i=0;i<nodee.getChildNodes().getLength();i++)
{
Node node=nodee.getChildNodes().item(i);
if(node.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("STATE sname")){
Log.i("TAG","from node::" + node.getTextContent());

countryname.add(node.getTextContent());
countrySelector.setAdapter(countryname);


countrySelector.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

}
else if(node.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("DISTRICT dname")){
Log.i("TAG","to node::" + node.getTextContent());
countryid.add(node.getTextContent());
}
}
}


is.close();
}
catch(Exception e){
System.out.println("ERROR while parsing xml:----" + e.getMessage());
}
```

this parsing used and use spinner to display the values